# How do I refresh the provisioning profiles for existing Xcode apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Recently, all copies of our IOS app (built directly from Xcode, not app store) have stopped working. I think this was caused by a developer license renewal. It was my first time renewing the license, so am not completely familiar with the process.

The app begins to open, then immediately closes. I think it is because of the Provisioning profiles expiring. In XCode the project was set to Automatic Signing. When I connected an iPad to the Mac and opened the console I found the message "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found". Since then, I've generated new certificates and created both Developer and Distribution Profiles.

I am able to build new versions successfully from XCode, but the apps that previously exist continue to not function. Is it even possible to fix this issue? I've searched for solutions but this isn't clear

Comment: You would need to distribute new copies of your app signed with new profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I distribute a new copy of the app, any data stored within the current one will be lost. Is there definitely no way?

Comment: This is a consequence of distributing your app by building directly from XCode. That's for development, not stable releases.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to build new versions successfully from XCode, but the apps that previously exist continue to not function. Is it even possible to fix this issue?

As Rudedog suggested in a comment, you'll need to distribute the app signed with your new, valid certificate.

> Thanks for the reply, if I distribute a new copy of the app, any data stored within the current one will be lost. Is there definitely no way?

As long as the bundle identifier hasn't changed and the old app isn't first deleted, updating to a new version of your app shouldn't remove existing application data on the device. Don't just take my word for it -- it's been a while since I used ad hoc distribution, so test to confirm that it works. But in general it's true: if you update an app from the App Store, you certainly don't lose the data on your device. And during development, each new build of your app installed on a device or simulator doesn't remove data written by previously-installed builds.